# my localhost page shows error No default engine

Tags: ejs, nodemon

I was trying to run my app throw nodemon locally but the page keep loading and shows nothing

the list.ejs file

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.set('view engine','ejs');
var day = "";
app.get("/",function(req,res){
   var today = new Date();
   if(today.getDay()===5 || today.getDay()===6){
       day = "weekend";
   } else {
       day = "weekday";
   }
    app.render("list",{kindofday:day});
})

app.listen(5000,function(){
    console.log("server is running on 5000");
})
```

error message :

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (C:\Users\faisa\Web Development\toollist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:61:11)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\faisa\Web Development\toollist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
    at C:\Users\faisa\Web Development\toollist-v1\app.js:13:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\faisa\Web Development\toollist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\faisa\Web Development\toollist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\faisa\Web Development\toollist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\faisa\Web Development\toollist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\faisa\Web Development\toollist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\faisa\Web Development\toollist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\faisa\Web Development\toollist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the view directory
`app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));`
replace views with the name of your directory